# Values are overriden in my ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a problem, or I don't understand a code snippet:
Here it is:

```
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        Person person = new Person();
        person.prename = "Klaus";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            person.surname = String.valueOf(i);
            persons.add(person);
            System.out.println(person.prename + ". " + person.surname);
        }
        System.out.println("=======");

        for (Person person1 : persons) {
            System.err.println(person1.prename + ". " + person1.surname);
        }
```

The result is:

```
Klaus. 0
Klaus. 1
Klaus. 2
Klaus. 3
Klaus. 4
=======
Klaus. 4
Klaus. 4
Klaus. 4
Klaus. 4
Klaus. 4
```

Why are the values overriden in the List persons? And how can I prevent such a result?

Comment: You're adding several references to the same `Person` object. Create a new `Person` object for each iteration of the loop. (This is a duplicate of *many* questions, but I suspect it'll be hard to find one quickly...)

Comment: Your Person class is a reference type, so you are updating the same reference over and over again inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using only one object and making change in that `Object` so the last change will only be applied to `Object`

```
Person person = new Person();//Move it inside loop
```

Declare it inside loop to create new `Objects`.

*Move following statements inside loop.*

```
Person person = new Person();
person.prename = "Klaus";
```

BTW

```
person.surname = String.valueOf(i);//I appreciate this rather than ""+i
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create the person inside the loop. As of now you are creating outside the loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.prename = "Klaus";
            person.surname = String.valueOf(i);
            persons.add(person);
            System.out.println(person.prename + ". " + person.surname);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You insert the same object reference each time and afterwards change the contents - but the object references still point to the same person. Solution: Create a new object for each iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.prename = "Klaus";
    person.surname = String.valueOf(i);
    persons.add(person)
    System.out.println(person.prename + ". " + person.surname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you were setting same person 5 times, try this:

```
Person person = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            person = new Person();
            person.prename = "Klaus";
            person.surname = String.valueOf(i);
            persons.add(person);
            System.out.println(person.prename + ". " + person.surname);
        }
```